# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing a tutorial in which the author has not updated his content to reflect changes in the PHP documentation. Anyways, I need to know what is parameter is being asked of me to provide. I've checked that all things are in order, but I literally don't know what I'm supposed to provide. Here's what I have:

**Connects.php**

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PwdSQL5');
mysqli_select_db('phpcadet') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

And yet I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:...

Comment: See the manual on [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/mysqli_select_db), add the missing connection parameter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`mysqli_select_db()` should have ***2*** parameters, the connection link and the database name - so the error message exactly says

```
mysqli_select_db($con, 'phpcadet');
```

Answer (score 4):

This error message is telling you that you need to provide the mysqli connection object as the first argument to the [`mysqli_select_db()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) function. Most of mysqli functions require the mysqli object when used in the procedural style.

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PwdSQL5');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'phpcadet')
//               ^^^^ - pass the $con object from the line above
```

However, **you don't need to use `mysqli_select_db()` at all**. You can pass the database name as the fourth argument to the [`mysqli_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) function. All you need is this:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PwdSQL5', 'phpcadet');
//                                  the database name - ^^^^^^
```